# OpenCv create 3 channel Mat from continuous data array

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mat, opencv-mat

I'd like to create an OpenCV 3-channel Mat using data allocated elsewhere where the pixels of each channel are together, unlike the data for an OpenCV Mat where the data from different channels is interleaved.

```
Mat outputMat = Mat(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC3, rawData); 
// This works only if rawData interleaves channel data like an OpenCv Mat
```

Is there a way to create an OpenCV Mat without having to resort to the below solution of splitting channels from a temporary Mat and copying the right channel data to the corresponding location?

```
void createMat(unsigned char *rawData, unsigned int dimX, unsigned int dimY)
{
    Mat outputMat = Mat(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC3);

    // use outputMat to draw some stuff

    Mat channelR = Mat(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC1, rawData);
    Mat channelG = Mat(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC1, rawData + dimX * dimY);
    Mat channelB = Mat(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC1, rawData + 2 * dimX * dimY);

    std::vector<Mat> channels(3);
    split(outputMat, channels);

    channels[2].copyTo(channelR);
    channels[1].copyTo(channelG);
    channels[0].copyTo(channelB);
}
```

I need to do this operation frequently, so I was wondering if there is a solution that doesn't involve calling the `split()` and `copyTo()` functions each time.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: How about `merge(channels,outputMat)`?

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't seem to work. The correct data doesn't go to the right channel. It is still interleaved.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, Do you want to get `RGB` channels in same manner from an OpenCV mat ?

Comment: Not exactly. I wish to create an OpenCV Mat with external data where the RGB channels are not interleaved, but rather each channel is stored one after the other.

Comment: Your statement is ambiguous to me. What does "not interleaved" refer to, the channels of the Mat, the channels of the external data, or both?

Comment: I added an illustration showing how the different channels are defined for a 2x2 Mat in both cases. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid `split` and `copyTo` by using `merge` directly.

```
Mat createMat(unsigned char *rawData, unsigned int dimX, unsigned int dimY)
{
    // No need to allocate outputMat here
    Mat outputMat;

    // Build headers on your raw data
    Mat channelR(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC1, rawData);
    Mat channelG(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC1, rawData + dimX * dimY);
    Mat channelB(dimY, dimX, CV_8UC1, rawData + 2 * dimX * dimY);

    // Invert channels, 
    // don't copy data, just the matrix headers
    std::vector<Mat> channels{ channelB, channelG, channelR };

    // Create the output matrix
    merge(channels, outputMat);

    return outputMat;
}
```

---

I tested a few other approaches, but they result to be slower. Just for the records, I thought this would be faster, but the transpose is really heavy:

```
Mat outputMat(3, dimY*dimX, CV_8UC1, rawData);
Mat tmp = outputMat.t();
outputMat = tmp.reshape(3, dimY);
cvtColor(outputMat, outputMat, COLOR_RGB2BGR);
```

Comment: `merge(channels, outputMat);` doesn't seem to use the same data as `rawData`. For example, setting `outputMat.at<Vec3b>(0, 0) = Vec3b(128, 128, 128);` doesn't reflect the values at the locations `rawData[0]`, `rawData[dimX * dimY]` and `rawData[2 * dimX * dimY]`. I checked, and it looks like `outputMat.ptr<unsigned char>(0) != rawData`

Comment: 1) the changes to `outputMat` are not reflected back in `rawData`. The data are deep copied while using `merge`. Since you're using a different layout than OpenCV, if you want to use your data you need to deep copy the data. 2) Obviously the data pointed by `outputMat` are different from `rawData`... you need to _interleave_ your original data to use them in a `Mat`.

Comment: That's what I feared. For my application, I'm using OpenCV to draw some stuff and display in another application which allocates `rawData`. So, seems like whenever I change the content of the `outputMat` I need to do a deep copy for the changes to reflect in `rawData`. If I have a high refresh rate, there's a lot of overhead to manually __interleave__ the data. If I understood it correctly, looks like there is no solution where I could do this just once and the subsequent changes in my OpenCV `outputMat` would reflect automatically in `rawData`. Thanks for the reply. @Miki

Comment: Exactly. Some solutions to overcome the _refresh_ would be to: 1) change the data layout your other application, 2) don't use OpenCV and make your own `Matrix` structure and the needed functions. If you just want to draw stuff, this shouldn't be difficult. 3) Use a library with the same data layout

Comment: What about YUV420? The split method seems to return just one channel with the initial Mat.